# ASP.MVC editors for types with same names

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, editorfor

In my solution there are two classes with identical names, but those classes come from different vendors and are located in different namespaces. In my Shared/EditorTemplates folder I have editor for one of them, for the other type I place editor in specific view folders. So my question is: is there a way to have Editors for types that have identical names (different namespaces) in Shared/E

Answer (score 0):

You can't have them both under Shared, but you could have one under shared and one under [Controller]\EditorTemplates.

Another solution would be to create a view model that inherits from one of the classes and make sure it has a unique name.